# Django Celery cache lock did not work?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to use Django cache to implement a lock mechanism. In Celery offical [site](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html), it claimed Django cache work fine for this. However, in my experence, it did not work. My experience is that if there are multiple threads/processes acquire the lock in almost the same time (close to ~0.003 second), all threads/processes will get the lock successfully. For other threads which acquire lock later than ~0.003 second, it fails.

Am I the only person experienced this? Please correct me if possible.

```
def acquire(self, block = False, slp_int = 0.001):
    while True:
        added = cache.add(self.ln, 'true', self.timeout)

        if added:
            cache.add(self.ln + '_pid', self.pid, self.timeout)
            return True

        if block:
            sleep(slp_int)
            continue
        else:
            return False


# Set Django backend cache to localcache
CACHES = { 
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': '/dev/shm/django_cache',                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Django makes no guarantees as to the atomicity of `.add()`. **Whether or not `.add()` will in fact be atomic depends on the backend you are using.** With a `FileBasedCache`, `.add()` is not atomic:

```
def add(self, key, value, timeout=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, version=None):
    if self.has_key(key, version):
        return False
    self.set(key, value, timeout, version)
    return True
```

Worker A executing `.add()` could be preempted after `self.has_key(...)` but before `self.set(...)`. Worker B executing `.add()` in one shot would successfully set the key and return `True`. When worker A resumes, it would also set the key and return `True`.

This [issue report](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2926) indicates that the example code you looked at assumes that the backend is Memcached. If you use Memcached or a backend that supports an atomic `.add()` then it should work.

Comment: memcached and the default locmem are atomic https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/